# How to implement the following in React Native Redux - Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an action called `fetchProperties` to fetch some listings and some data related data of all. The response looks like this and I'm setting Redux store with this information (20 listings).

```
{
  "status":"success",
  "listings":[
             {
               "id": "1",
               "streetnum": "370",
               "streetname": "Pack Saddle Drive",
               "city": "Horseshoe Bay",
               "area": "Blue Lake Estates",
               "zipcode": "78657",
             },
             {...}
             // 20 out of 300 properties
             ],
  "total_found":300,
  "some_other" : "some other data"
}
```

During the next call to fetch the next 20 listings, the API returns a same structure as above but I want to append the new `listings` array to the old `listings` array in the Redux store.

For this kind of scenario how to write the reducer? I tried like below but it didn't work,

```
    export default function propertiesList(state = { listings: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PROPERTIES:
      // return action.payload.body;
      return {
        ...state,
        listings: [...state.listings, ...action.payload.body]
      };
}
```

and the final state should like this:

```
{
  "status":"success",
  "listings":[
             {
               "id": "1",
               "streetnum": "370",
               "streetname": "Pack Saddle Drive",
               "city": "Horseshoe Bay",
               "area": "Blue Lake Estates",
               "zipcode": "78657",
             },
             {...}
             // 40 out of 300 properties
             ],
  "total_found":300,
  "some_other" : "some other data"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the reducer to like this.

```
export default function propertiesList(state = { listings: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PROPERTIES:
      return {
        ...action.payload.body,
        listings: [...state.listings, ...action.payload.body.listings]
      };
    case EMPTY_PROPERTIES_STORE:
      return { listings: [] };
  }
```

and also before calling the `fetchProperties` for the first time, I called action `EMPTY_PROPERTIES_STORE` to make sure my empty store contains empty `listings` array

Answer (score 1):

You just have to append the listings with your old listings on success case of reducer, like:

```
case FETCH_PROPERTIES:
  return { 
    ...state, 
    listings: [
      ...state.listings,
      ...action.payload.body,
    ]
  }
```

assuming FETCH_PROPERTIES is your success case

Comment: It is breaking. How will the above reducer sets the initial data.

Comment: you would have initialised your listings with empty array right ? then even for the first tie you are just spreading an empty array and no harm in that

Comment: I think its breaking because it should be `...action.payload.body.listings`, so you can merge both arrays. Also, do you really need to save all the other info? Seems like you only need the listings.

Comment: Yes, I need all other info too. I'm using those in other parts of component

Comment: @warl0ck, yes Im defining an empty array in reducer. like     export default function propertiesList(state = { listings: [] }, action) { still imgetting error, Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: this means your action.payload.bosy is undefined maybe, just a guess but with this information thats all i can tell

Comment: I could able to append the listings to the old state but the remaining object is not being in state.